# How to change the frequency of update check for Window 10 store?

Tags: windows-10, windows-store

I want to increase the frequency the windows 10 store checks for app updates.
I can't find any info about it, does anyone have any idea how to do it or is it even possible?

Comment: I would guess this is the same as Windows Update.

Comment: I have looked at this in Reliability History. On average the checks and subsequent updates happen about weekly.

Comment: That's very long, any way to make them daily?

Comment: No. The apps do not update daily, so they update your machine when new versions come out

Comment: I'm using Insider version of Windows and I want store to check for updates more regularly than weekly cycle.